# I'm unable to browse an external HDD on a Windows 10 laptop but can mount and view the files on Ubuntu & Android

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive, filesystems, data-recovery

The NTFS formatted hard-drive shows up ‘Local Disk (F:)’ in Explorer. When trying to open it, the error window states:

> F:\ is not accessible.
>   The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

In the title bar:

> Location is not available

The drive usually shows up as 'Toshiba HDD (:)'. The 'General' window in properties is blank - without any space or name details of the drive.

*However*, on my rooted Android, I can mount, read & write files using the app ‘exFAT/NTFS for Total Commander’ with an OTG cable.

I'm also able to perform all operations on the drive when using Ubuntu Studio.
The drive does not show any errors in Ubuntu or GParted.

It's Possible to mount 2 HDDs with Android but takes ages to copy data:

[image]

While defragmenting the HDD, Windows blue-screened on me. After this, it seldom allowed me to mount & view the HDD.

The first few time I connected the HDD via OTG and then connected it back to the laptop, I was able to view the HDD as normal again (Android 6.0). But recently this trick hasn't been working for me. I recently replaced the motherboard on the phone and was using a different app before.

**How can I resolve this to browse the HDD on my PC without losing my data?**

It's a Toshiba StorE Alu2 2TB HDD with USB 2.0

Edit 1: HDD is tested and working with Ubuntu Studio. Looking for ways to defragment within Ubuntu & Linux to complete an interrupted defrag operation on Windows.

Comment: Well, whatever you do, don't write anything to the drive until you have a good idea of what to do to fix the problem.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling The first few time I connected the HDD via OTG and then connected it back to the laptop, I was able to view the HDD as normal again (Android 6.0). But recently this trick hasn't been working for me. I recently replaced the motherboard on the phone and was using a different app before, the difference now probably comes from there.

Comment: My guess here would be that something in the file system is sufficiently corrupted that Windows is unhappy about it, but sufficiently correct that the Android application is able to read the data (by whatever means it uses). Do you have anywhere you could make a sector-level copy of the problematic drive? Having a copy *would* allow testing even potentially destructive recovery methods.

Comment: I have another 160GB external but there's over a Terabyte of data on the problematic drive. I connected the HDD to another Win10 laptop with the same result. This issue arose since Windows Blue-Screened on me while I was defragging the drive using 'Defraggler' by Piriform. @MichaelKjörling

Comment: Well, a hard interrupted defragmentation could certainly cause all kinds of file system corruption, especially if the defragmentation software isn't carefully designed to avoid creating inconsistent situations while shuffling data around. All that said, are we to take the above as that you have no backup of the data on the drive? (That's very much living on the edge in and of itself, regardless of your current problem.)

Comment: Clone the drive, then (after you've made a copy) try `chkdsk` on it.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I don't have sufficient storage space to clone the HDD to. The only medium I'm able to browse the drive on is on my Android phone. Copying files there takes ages too. After about 5 minutes it's able to detect and mount 2x drives. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct9OQ.jpg

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Quite the predicament indeed, there's valuable data on the drive although I do not need to access it urgently, it's more of a terrible inconvenience. Copying the data too will take forever this way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ct9OQ.jpg

Comment: @Darshan, well you could of course try my software [RecuperaBit](http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271) to access it and copy some file. But one way or another, you will need some space to store the extracted files. If you don't have another drive, buy it. Assuming you want to recover the data.

Comment: Of course it takes a lot to copy stuff with your phone, you are splitting a USB connection (maybe even USB 2) with two I/O devices.